# Does a server-called PHP script run asynchronously?

Tags: php, ubuntu, server

If a PHP script is called by the server via command line (on an Ubuntu server), can multiple instances of that script be running at the same time? In my case, it's a PHP script that converts uploaded video using FFmpeg. So if eight users upload a video at the same moment (or very close to it), will eight instances of that PHP script be running simultaneously, or will they queue up, one after another? If they queue up, is there a way to change it so that multiple instances CAN run simultaneously?

Comment: Multiple instances of the same script can indeed run at the same time.

Comment: Thanks - that's all I needed to know! If you leave an answer I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple instances of the same script can indeed run at the same time. The thing to note is that performance will degrade the more scripts run at the same time. Also you should note that if you're interacting with a database, and you `LOCK` a table for writing, that cannot be done asynchronously and will cause a queue to form (albeit a minor one, depending on the operations that are being done).

**Proof**

You can check this by creating a PHP script that calls `exec()` somewhere within and executes another PHP script (or indeed the same one - but be careful not to create an infinite loop). Perhaps spitting a timestamp to a file or a database so that you can adequately see it happening.

Comment: "performance will degrade the more scripts run at the same time." most php scripts use a fraction of any servers resources, so it can be quite a few scripts running at the same time before there is any measurable performance degradation. for some tasks running multiple scripts will increase the over all performance

Comment: @Dagon depends how good/bad the code is ;). If you write really clunky intensive code it does have the potential to create a bottleneck. Even really clean code can still be slower running multiple times compared with just a single time (but I agree, that difference will be negligible). I felt it was worth pointing out before he went and did some crazy `run x 100000000` script.

Comment: Plus in my case, the PHP scripts are calling FFmpeg using shell_exec, so... yeah... can definitely degrade server performance :)

Comment: @PeregrineStudios well... depends on the servers ;)!